# How can I pass Parameters to the Form with this Generic Method?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have this generic method to open forms within a panel, this method inherits from `Form`, currently with the restriction that it has an empty constructor `(where T : Form, new())`

```
public void OpenForms<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    Form form = container_panel.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (form !=null)
    {
        //If the instance is minimized we leave it in its normal state
        if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        //If the instance exists, I put it in the foreground
        form.BringToFront();
        return;
    }
    //The form opens
    form = new T();
    form.TopLevel = false;
    container_panel.Controls.Add(form);
    container_panel.Tag = form;
    form.Show();
}
```

In this way to call it:

```
OpenForms<Form1>();
```

**How can I adapt this function to pass parameters to the form?**

In this case I need to pass two parameters to the form, something like this:

```
OpenForms<Form1>(param1, param2);
```

> Not all forms receive parameters, but in the future, you may need to use 1/2/3 parameters depending on the form.
>
> The parameters can vary in type, either: `bool`, `string`, `int` ...

That this can receive something like this:

```
public void OpenForms<T>(params object[] args) where T : Form, new() { ... }
```

---

The idea is to be able to use it in the following way:

```
object[] args = new object[] { "a", true };

OpenForms<Form1>(args);
OpenForms<Form1>("a", 2, false);
OpenForms<Form1>();
```

When you receive the parameters, you can use them when creating the form.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

**Edit:**

I suppose these two examples of forms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(string param1, bool param2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //......
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //......
}
```

When trying to make the call like this:

```
OpenForms<Form1>("a" false); //Error
OpenForms<Form2>();
```

Error:

> must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'AbrirFormulario(params object[])'

Comment: What are you having trouble with? You know how to declare the method and give it arguments. What's the hitch? Are you asking how to pass them along them to the form itself?

Comment: You can't do it with generics, you need to do it with reflection. In that case, you will need to remove the `new()` constraint to allow forms without parameterless constructors.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Error: `must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'OpenForms<T>(params object[])'`

Comment: @J.Rodríguez I think that you got that error message on some code you tried to compile. Please add that code to your question.

Comment: @RonBeyer The idea is to allow forms with parameters and without parameters, both can you show me an example in an answer?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Working on it....

Comment: @J.Rodríguez So is Ron correct in guessing that you're required to pass these parameters to the constructor? Or at least that you think you are.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That compilation error is when using the method like this: `OpenForms<T>(params object[] args)`  and making the method call like this : `OpenForms<Form1>("a", 2, false);`

Comment: @EdPlunkett The error doesn't pop up where you may think you would have to pass a `Form` that does not have a parameterless constructor to the method, then you will get the error that was described.

Comment: @RonBeyer Ahhh, yes of course, my bad. But yeah, if he's going to use it with forms that don't have parameterless constructors, `new()` has to go.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Check, edit the question and if it gives an error

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Right, I wasn't thinking. You'll have to get rid of the `new()` constraint if you want to allow Forms without parameterless construtors. But Ron's already got it all figured out I think.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez what are these "parameters" used for? are you setting properties in the form instance? it seems to me that losing type safety is never a good idea.

Comment: @FedericoBerasategui I am not an expert in this, check the edition of my question, the way I use the forms and the parameters, is it wrong?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez but, what are you `exactly` trying to do with these parameters? what do you use them for?

Comment: @FedericoBerasategui To make validations in the form, since this form uses different processes and will work with a process depends on which option the form is invoked, with this parameter I can specify that it is invoked from a menu, from another form etc.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez I don't think a form is the right place to define "different processes". Forms are part of the UI, not the business logic.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Do you have any other ideas? can suggest it in response, [look at this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496434/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-the-form-with-this-generic-method/50496567?noredirect=1#comment88007098_50496567), the method that Ron says correctly receives the parameters but I can not adapt the code to show the form in the `Panel`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I do not agree, the form if it can be shown on the panel, currently that's what the method does, only that combined with the Ron code I can not get it to work

Comment: I still fail to understand why would the form have different constuctor parameters and why you want to lose type safety like this. You might as well just forget C# and use javascript if you don't care about properly using a correct type system.

Comment: @FedericoBerasategui Do not be offended, I just want help, Let's see if I can explain it For example: parameter1 will receive a text to be used as a name in a `Label`, parameter2, to make certain validations inside the form, if` True` executes a method, if it is `false` that executes another, this I need because this same form can be invoked from different parts of the system and depending on where it is invoked it will have a different behavior on the screen. Is an Example, can you understand?

Comment: Example 1 seems okay but I would just expose a property for that and then allow the generic method to receive an params Action<T>[] or whatever to be invoked on the form upon creation.

Example 2 seems really out of place because validations and such belong in a ViewModel or Controller depending on your taste, but NOT on the UI.

Comment: @FedericoBerasategui I understand, since I am not an expert, I try to do things as well as possible, and many times I am forced to do things one way, because my employer asks me to be X or Y form the programming and I have to stick to what I request the boss, You can post an answer to help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to remove the `new()` constraint to allow forms without parameterless constructors:

```
public void OpenForms<T>(params object[] args) where T : Form
```

Now, in order to create the instance, you need to use `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
T form = default(T);

if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
    form = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
else
    form = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
```

#### Edit: Full Solution

```
public void OpenForms<T>(params object[] args) where T : Form
{
    Form form = container_panel.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (form !=null)
    {
        //If the instance is minimized we leave it in its normal state
        if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        //If the instance exists, I put it in the foreground
        form.BringToFront();
        return;
    }
    if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        form = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    else
        form = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    form.TopLevel = false;
    container_panel.Controls.Add(form);
    container_panel.Tag = form;
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I'll adapt your code to my method and perform tests and I'll tell you if it works like this.

Comment: If you receive the parameter, but can not show the form inside the panel after adapting your code, you can edit your response and place your code following the rules contained in the other codes?

Comment: This is the way I have adapted his code to mine:[look at the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5bUM.png) but it does not show the form in the panel :(, can you edit your answer and place how the method should eventually go?

Comment: What is `container_panel`? It may take me some time to respond, I will be away from my computer for a while.

Comment: It is a `Panel` added in the designer `Panel container_panel;`

Comment: @J.Rodríguez I modified the solution, it works fine for me as long as `form.Show()` is called, if it is not, the form doesn't show up in the panel.

Comment: I have posted another alternative solution, take a look to see what you think.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to create an `Interface` to create a method that allows receiving the parameters.

This is an example:

```
public interface IForms
{
    void InitializeParameters(params object[] args);
}
```

Here we define a method, `InitializeParameters` that must comply with the forms that implement this interface.

Later, in the forms that must be called from the generic form, we add the interface in its definition, and the obligatory method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IForms
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void InitializeParameters(params object[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length==2)
        {
            string param1 = args[0].ToString();
            int param2 = (int)args[1];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("The number of parameters is incorrect");
        }

    }       
}
```

Now we define the generic method to open the forms in the following way:

```
private void OpenForms<T>(params object[] args) where T : Form,IForms,  new()
{
    Form form;
    form= new T();
    ((IForms)form).InitializeParameters(args);
    form.Show();
}
```

Finally, the way to use it would be the following:

```
OpenForms<Form1>("a", 2);
OpenForms<Form2>("a", 2, "b");
OpenForms<Form3>();
```

> It must be taken into account that as the `InitializeParameters` method has been defined, examples 2 and 3 **will give an exception for an incorrect number of parameters**. With this form, each case must be controlled.

Thanks to the user [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) for your help.

Comment: This works, but the one thing I don't like is that you use `params object[] args` in the form to "initialize" the form. The coder has no idea what the parameters are or what order they belong in. At least with the constructor approach, you can have `public Form(string someUsefulParameterName, bool someOtherUsefulName)` The more I think about it, a better approach would be the use of a constructor `Func`, I'll post something that shows how to use it.

Comment: @RonBeyer I understand, then make the publication, the better the focus, the better the functioning and understanding will be. and thanks friend

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet an alternative approach that does not require the `Form` to implement an interface or really care how it is constructed.

Let's say we have a `Form`, just for testing purposes:

```
public class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3(bool someParameter, string someTitle)
    {

    }
}
```

Now there are some useful self-documenting features about the constructor, namely that the parameters have names. Using something like this:

```
public void OpenForms<T>(params object[] args) where T : Form
{
    //...
}
```

Doesn't give the caller any information about what the "arguments" are, what order they belong in, or what they mean. So when you call it like this:

```
OpenForms<Form3>(true, "Some Value");
```

The Intellisense doesn't help you because it just shows that you need to pass some (or no) parameters to the method. Instead the better way to do this is to use a factory `Func<T>` to construct the form:

```
public void OpenForms<T>(Func<T> factoryMethod) where T : Form
{
    Form form = container_panel.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (form != null)
    {
        //If the instance is minimized we leave it in its normal state
        if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        //If the instance exists, I put it in the foreground
        form.BringToFront();
        return;
    }
    form = factoryMethod();
    form.TopLevel = false;
    container_panel.Controls.Add(form);
    container_panel.Tag = form;
    form.Show();
}
```

Which is then called like this (notice how you can also leave off the `<Form3>` part of the OpenForms call, it is inferred!):

```
OpenForms(() => new Form3(true, "Title"));
```

With all the helpful intellisense that goes along with it:

[image]

So now you have self-documenting code, it doesn't matter how the form is constructed, and you are not forcing an interface that has no real documentation (in code) about what parameters belong where.

Comment: Waoo, I'm impressed by the way you work, thank you, I think it's great, my friend, I thank you very much for taking the time to explain each case to me.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I have a small question. In the method to look for the form within the panel I use this:
`Form form = container_panel.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();` so as to prevent the same `form` from being opened more than once, **How could under a certain condition allow a specific form to be can open more than once inside the panel?**

For example, if the `Form3` allows to open it as many times as the user wants, but the other `Form1`, `Form2` allow only one instance?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Just add a parameter to the method, something like `public void OpenForms<T>(Func<T> factoryMethod, bool allowMultiInstance = false) where T : Form { ... }` and if that parameter is true, don't run the first check to see if it is running.

Comment: Thank you, exactly how I solved it a long time ago, thank you very much!

Comment: As a thank you for your help, I have taken a look at some of your answers to other questions, and I voted for you, your answers are very well formulated, I congratulate you and again, thank you friend.

Comment: No problem, take care